# How to append columns of different formats

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle 11.g
I have a table with three columns:

```
ID            Varchar2(512)
FIRST_NAME    Varchar2(512)
LAST_NAME     Varchar2(512)
```

The ID column stores both numbers and alpha characters.  I'd like to select three columns from the table: ID, LAST_NAME and FIRST_NAME.
I'd like to Order by the ID column, but have the numbers sort as numbers and appear first.

For example:

```
ID       FN   LN 
3        Joe  Jones 
200      Sam  Smith 
1004     Tom  Terrific 
AA       Cam  Carson 
MM       Ed   Edison
```

How would I go about constructing the Select Statement for this?
I can get the Numbers-only by using:

```
Select to_number(ID), LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME
    From CUSTOM_TABLE
    Where ID < 'A'
    Order by to_number(ID);
```

And I can get the Alpha's only by using:

```
Select ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME
    From CUSTOM_TABLE
    Where ID > 'A'
    Order by ID;
```

I've experimented with Union  / Union ALL but can't seem to get the results I want.
Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with multiple keys:

```
order by (case when regexp_like(id, '^[0-9]+$') then 1 else 2 end),
         (case when regexp_like(id, '^[0-9]+$') then cast(id as int) end),
         id
```

This says:

- If `id` is a number, put it first.
- If `id` is a number, then order by the number.
- Otherwise, order by the `id` itself as a string.

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  That worked perfectly.  Just what I wanted: 3, 200, 1004, AA, MM